# Select not working Unix C

Tags: c, unix, select, pipe

```
fd_set read_fds;
struct timeval tv;
while(1){
    tv.tv_sec = 3;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(0,&read_fds);
    FD_SET(pipelogin,&read_fds);
    nfd = select(1,&read_fds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
    if(FD_ISSET(0,&read_fds)){
         printf("Comando"); }
         //comandos();
    if(FD_ISSET(pipelogin,&read_fds)){
         printf("Login"); }
         //VerificaLogin(pipelogin);
}
```

My function "comandos()" just read commands from user and do something and function VerificaLogin(pipelogin) just let the user login or not. I can only user "comando" once and VerificaLogin only works after the first "comando"...Can someone tell me what's wrong in here ?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: The first parameter of `select` should be at least 1 plus the maximum file descriptor in the set. Since you only have two file descriptors in the set, `0` and `pipelogin`, then `pipelogin` will be the maximum file descriptor in the set, so set the first parameter to `pipelogin+1` as so: `nfd = select(pipelogin+1,&read_fds,NULL,NULL,&tv);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott that's right thanks, but keeps doing the same thing.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. (See [mcve].)

Comment: Prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to the old, nearly obsolete, `select`. Also, put a `\n` at end of `printf` format string, or use `fflush`

Answer (score 1):

The `select` function is a status-reporting function. Unless the status changes, it will continue to report the same status.

Also, you should *never* use `select` with blocking sockets. That will only cause pain.